# node concurrent http request throttling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a number of hosts in a datacenter. The hosts are only network accessible via a HTTP load balancer which I have the IP address for. Each host has the same restful service which provides hostname and other host specific information I am after. I have a node app running in another location, which will submit HTTP GET requests to the load balancer. These requests will be serviced by whichever host the load balancer assigns the request to. My question is about how to code node for concurrent, throttled HTTP GET requests. I am new to javascript and trying to understand what is the best practice around using async, promises or native callbacks, or what combination of those is required.

My requirements:

1. Fire requests from Node to the load balancer with a maximum concurrent request limit configurable in the code.
2. Keep making http requests until I have responses from a configurable number of hosts, each Host responds with it's hostname and other info.
3. A configurable maximum total HTTP requests limit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you as it requires learning a new library.

Anyway... You could use [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) to do what you want [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qixitiwule/edit?js,console) Feel free to ask any questions you may have.

```
import Rx from 'rx';

var concurrency = 2;
var maxRequests = 100;
var maxDistinct = 3;


// mock of your actual request function
// instead of setTimout you should make an actual request and onNext the response of that
var hostIndex = 0;
function executeRequest(requestConfig) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observable => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('start request ', hostIndex);
      observable.onNext({request: requestConfig, response: 42, hostname: hostIndex});
      hostIndex += 1;
      observable.onCompleted();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var endObservable = new Rx.Subject();
var requests = Rx.Observable.from( ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6'] );
var responses = requests
      .take(maxRequests)   // only take in this many urls (you could do that by limiting the size of the array, did I misunderstand you here?)
      .map(executeRequest)
      .merge(concurrency)  // limit concurrently running observables
      .takeUntil(endObservable) // stop the observable and thereby any remaining requests once endObservable fires
      .publish(); // makes multiple subscriptions use the same underlying source - needed so requests are not executed multiple times.

// your actual responses
responses.subscribe(value => console.log(value),
                    error => console.log(error),
                    ended => console.log('completed'));

// controls when the stream ends due to maxDistinct hosts being reached
responses
  .scan((state, currentResponse) => {
    // keep list of unique hosts that responded
    state.hosts[currentResponse.hostname] = true;
    return state;
  }, { hosts: {} })
  .subscribe(state => {
    var distinctHosts = Object.keys(state.hosts).length;
    if(distinctHosts >= maxDistinct) endObservable.onNext(); //if maxDistinct hosts has been reached emit an event on the endObservable, which terminates any remaining requests via .takeUntil(endObservable)
  });

responses.connect();
```